# Allow html tags in Angular controller or view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my contrller :

```
LandingApp.controller('LandingCtrl2', function($scope){
    $scope.articles = [
        {
            'imageSrc'   : IMG_DIR + 'spec9.jpg',
            'title'      : 'Stencils',
            'description': 'Plastic or thin metal stencils.<br/>100% Custom made'
        }
    ];
});
```

when i try in My ng repeat (...article in articles...) {{article.description}}
i got `...  stencils.<br/>100% ....` , but i need break line or some other html tags. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a method, which can tell `AngularJS` to render that string as a `HTML`

Example :

```
$scope.renderHtml = function (htmlCode) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
}
```

And in your `view`:

```
<div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(article.description)"></div>
```

Don't forget to include `$sce` in your controller

```
LandingApp.controller('LandingCtrl2', function($scope,$sce){ ...
```